# Recursive Generators in Python

Tags: python, recursion, generator, bioinformatics

I wrote a function to return a generator containing every unique combination of sub-strings a given length that contain more than n elements from a primary string.

As an illustration:

if i have 'abcdefghi' and a probe of length of two, and a threshold of 4 elements per list i'd like to get:

```
['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh']
['ab', 'de', 'fg', 'hi']
['bc', 'de', 'fg', 'hi']
```

My first attempt at this problem involved returning a list of lists.  This ended up overflowing the memory of the computer.  As a crude secondary solution, I created a generator that does something similar.  The problem is that I created a nested generator that calls itself.  When I run this function, it seems to just loop around the inner for loop without actually calling itself again.  I thought that a generator would precede as far down the recursion hole as necessary until it hit the yield statement.  Any clue what is happening?

```
def get_next_probe(self, current_probe_list, probes, unit_length):
    if isinstance(current_probe_list, list):
        last_probe=current_probe_list[-1]
        available_probes = [candidate for candidate in probes if candidate.start>last_probe.end]
    else:
        available_probes = [candidate for candidate in probes if candidate.start<unit_length]

    if available_probes:

        max_position=min([probe.end for probe in available_probes])
        available_probes2=[probe for probe in available_probes if max_position+1>probe.start]

        for new_last_probe in available_probes2:
            new_list=list(current_probe_list)
            new_list.append(new_last_probe)
            self.get_next_probe(new_list, probes, unit_length)

    else:
        if len(current_probe_list)>=self.num_units:
            yield current_probe_list
```

If yield is changed to print this works just fine!  I'd appreciate any help I could get.  I realize this isn't an optimal implementation of this type of search problem, it seems like returning a list of found positions from the last call of get_next_probe and filtering this list for the elements that do not overlap new_last_probe.end would be far more efficient... but this was a lot easier for me to write.  Any algorithm input would still be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You don’t seem to be using the result from your recursive call. I would expect to see an inner loop that iterates over a sublit of the outer list, concatenating the result from a recursive call to form the result which is yielded.

Comment: You're missing a quote on the first line, ab, too

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I thought that a generator would precede as far down the recursion hole as necessary until it hit the yield statement

It will recurse fine, but to get the `yield`ed value to propogate back outward, you need to do it explicitly - just like if it was a `return`, you would need to explicitly `return` the result of each recursion. So, instead of:

```
 self.get_next_probe(new_list, probes, unit_length)
```

You would do something like:

```
 for val in self.get_next_probe(new_list, probes, unit_length):
     yield val
```

Or if you're using Python 3.3 or newer, you can also do this:

```
yield from self.get_next_probe(new_list, probes, unit_length)
```

Comment: Starting in Python 3.2, you can also just do `yield from self.get_next_prob(...)`.

Comment: @Dougal , `yield from` isn't in 3.2 but will be in 3.3 once it comes out.

Comment: Good point @Ivc...you'd thing I could check that before saying so, since I write most of my code in 3.2 these days anyway. :)